# How to update the content and class in a Polymer component?

Tags: polymer-1.0

In this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/teyexo/edit?html,output) how can I update the element's content and add a class?

It seems that `this.$.content.innerHTML = "Changed?"` and  `this.classList.add('new')` won't work.

The code in the jsbin is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>
  <my-element>Some text</my-element>
  <dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          background: lightgrey;
        }
        .new {
          background: blue;
        }
      </style>
      <content>
      </content>
      <button on-tap="make">Make blue</button>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'my-element',
          make: function() {
            this.$.content.innerHTML = "Changed?";
            this.classList.add('new');
          }
        })
      })
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
:host.new {
  background: blue;
}
...
make: function() {
  this.classList.add("new");
  Polymer.dom(this).innerHTML = "changed?";
}
```